# Gazebo crashes immediately on startup on Ubuntu 22.04 ARM VM on parallels desktop in MacBook Air M1

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ros, parallels, gazebo-simu

So I'm working with ROS2 on my MacBook air M1 and need gazebo for simulations. The OS I'm working with is Ubuntu 22.04 ARM on Parallels Desktop 18. I'm running ros2 [Humble](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation.html), and its gazebo counterpart [Gazebo Gardens](https://gazebosim.org/docs/garden/install_ubuntu). Rviz is running just fine, but when I start up the gazebo simulator running command

`gz sim`

gazebo opens up showing a menu of demos (I guess they are demos, one of them says 'NAO Joint Control'). When I click on the 'empty project' of any one of the demos, the editor-esque window opens but then instantly crashes. The terminal outputs following error message:

```
libGL error: pci id for fd 42: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
pci id for fd 43: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
libGL error: pci id for fd 44: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
pci id for fd 52: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
libEGL warning: pci id for fd 64: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)

pci id for fd 65: 1ab8:0010, driver (null)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::UnimplementedException'
  what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(9:UnimplementedException):  in GL3PlusTextureGpu::copyTo at ./RenderSystems/GL3Plus/src/OgreGL3PlusTextureGpu.cpp (line 685)
Stack trace (most recent call last):
#31   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffff93fcb06b, in QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#30   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffff9402b523, in QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>)
#29   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0xffff92e02f13, in g_main_context_iteration
#28   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0xffff92e5aeab, in 
#27   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0", at 0xffff92e05a6f, in g_main_context_dispatch
#26   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffff9402c057, in 
#25   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffff93fcff87, in QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendPostedEvents(QObject*, int, QThreadData*)
#24   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffff93fccb8f, in QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*)
#23   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5", at 0xffff95472abf, in QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)
#22   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5", at 0xffff93ffcfd3, in QObject::event(QEvent*)
#21   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0xffff58337dd7, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderWindowItem::Ready()
#20   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0xffff58337917, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThread::Initialize[abi:cxx11]()
#19   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0xffff58343d17, in gz::gui::plugins::RenderThreadRhiOpenGL::Initialize[abi:cxx11]()
#18   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gz-gui-7/plugins/libMinimalScene.so", at 0xffff5833b10f, in gz::gui::plugins::GzRenderer::Initialize[abi:cxx11]()
#17   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgz-rendering7.so.7", at 0xffff582c39c3, in gz::rendering::v7::BaseRenderEngine::CreateScene(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#16   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgz-rendering7.so.7", at 0xffff582cc03f, in gz::rendering::v7::BaseRenderEngine::CreateScene(unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
#15   Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgz-rendering7.so.7", at 0xffff582dfff3, in gz::rendering::v7::BaseScene::CreateMaterials()
#14   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gz-rendering-7/engine-plugins/libgz-rendering-ogre2.so", at 0xffff33b50423, in gz::rendering::v7::Ogre2Material::SetTextureMapImpl(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, Ogre::PbsTextureTypes)
#13   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0xffff337ab46b, in Ogre::TextureGpuManager::_waitFor(Ogre::TextureGpu*, bool)
#12   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0xffff337ab0af, in Ogre::TextureGpuManager::_update(bool)
#11   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0xffff3368ebaf, in Ogre::ObjCmdBuffer::execute()
#10   Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0xffff3368cf37, in Ogre::ObjCmdBuffer::NotifyDataIsReady::execute()
#9    Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/libOgreNextMain.so.2.3.1", at 0xffff3379cef3, in Ogre::TextureFilter::GenerateHwMipmaps::_executeSerial(Ogre::TextureGpu*)
#8    Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL3Plus.so", at 0xffff330f2633, in Ogre::GL3PlusTextureGpu::copyTo(Ogre::TextureGpu*, Ogre::TextureBox const&, unsigned char, Ogre::TextureBox const&, unsigned char, bool, Ogre::CopyEncTransitionMode::CopyEncTransitionMode, Ogre::CopyEncTransitionMode::CopyEncTransitionMode)
#7    Object "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/OGRE-2.3/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL3Plus.so", at 0xffff330b4997, in 
#6    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", at 0xffff971e2d23, in __cxa_throw
#5    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", at 0xffff971e2a3f, in std::terminate()
#4    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", at 0xffff971e29db, in 
#3    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6", at 0xffff971e51fb, in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()
#2    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffff9b22712f, in abort
#1    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffff9b23a67b, in raise
#0    Object "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", at 0xffff9b27f200, in 
Aborted (Signal sent by tkill() 13395 1000)
```

Has anyone got gazebo running on their MacBook with M1/M2 chip? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running with the old render engine (ogre instead of ogre2)?

> ign gazebo --render-engine ogre

Comment: yes, at least now the gazebo window actually opens, and I did insert my own mesh there as well. But it's completely unusable, as the world keeps glitching, seemingly reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 3d acceleration and "Always use high performance graphics" enabled? [Some people](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/ros-rviz-opengl-problem-on-ubuntu-20-04.351631/) in older versions had luck turning it off. For Parallels 18, others also had some issues relating to to the render engine ogre, which could help [here](https://forum.parallels.com/threads/black-screen-with-3d-acceleration-enabled-for-gazebo-and-rviz-robotic.355825/)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/issues/1841#issuecomment-1404172345), you can try to enable the environment variable LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE by putting `export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` in your .bashrc file.

With a different gazebo sim and an identical setup (except I have Parallels 19), I had the same error- after trying this, it was able to launch and work successfully.